# Why does this Shiny App return a 'Not Found' error after I refresh?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

When I upload an .Rmd file to shinyapps.io, initially (for the first 5 refreshes) the app works well (see screenshot with what it should look like). However, after I have refreshed the URL more than 5 times, I get a `Not Found` error message which replaces the table. Does anyone know why this is the case when I haven't amended the code or updated anything in between refreshes?

[image]

Comment: Are you using any randomization functions?

Comment: No, just visualising a couple of data frames which can be selected using the drop down bit in the screenshot.